# .NET Core variable does not exist / is blank in view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core

I have this ViewModel that I pass to my view:

```
public class CreateFormViewModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string FormPropertiesList { get; set; }
}
```

When I submit my form, FormPropertiesList will contain a JSON array which will be processed serverside.

However, the problem is that when I load the page, FormPropertiesList is empty. That means I won't be able to parse it unless it contains any data.

Right now this is the error I get

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token !==

This is my jquery code:

```
if (typeof @Model.FormPropertiesList !== 'undefined') {
    console.log(JSON.parse(@Model.FormPropertiesList));
}
```

In the console, I can see that @Model.FormPropertiesList is blank. Not a null or "" but blank.

I have tried to declare it as a null serverside before I load the page but the same issue occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that `@Model.FormPropertiesList` can output an empty string to the front-end logic then it would make more sense to check the length of the string before attempting to parse it.

Don't forget you need to add quotes on the client-side when you output the value so that it'll be correctly interpreted as a string:

```
if ('@Model.FormPropertiesList'.length !== 0) {
  var obj = JSON.parse('@Model.FormPropertiesList');
  console.log(obj);
}
```

Note that this can be made more succinct by coalescing the value:

```
var obj = JSON.parse('@Model.FormPropertiesList' || '{}');
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Oh! It worked! Thank you. I'll mark this as the answer. Never thought of it that way.

Comment: Glad it helped. I added another approach for you which negates the need for the `if` condition